# Trouble with Dynamic Menu on Codeigniter, using Array and MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, submenu

I try to implements @Tomas answer on this question > [PHP foreach create menu from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276922/php-foreach-create-menu-from-array)

I have Model below:

```
<?php
class Menu_model extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function getCategory($lang){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE category.lang='".mysql_real_escape_string($lang)."'";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $result;
    }

    function getSubCategory($lang){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE subcategory.lang='".mysql_real_escape_string($lang)."'";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $result;
    }

}
?>
```

Then I use this Controller to throw the data:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'EN';

class Home extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model("menu_model");
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data["category"] = $this->menu_model->getCategory($_SESSION['lang']);
        $data["subcategory"] = $this->menu_model->getSubCategory($_SESSION['lang']);

        $this->load->view('leftmenu_view',$data);//Left Menu
    }
}
```

This is my view to display the menu:

```
<?php
                foreach($category->result() as $menu){
                echo "<li><a class=\"sf-with-ul\" href=\"category/".$menu->urlcategory."\">".$menu->namecategory."</a></li>";
                    foreach($subcategory->result() as $key=>$submenu){
                        if ($menu->idcategory == $submenu->idcategory){
                            if ($key > 0){
                            echo "</li>";
                            }
                            echo "<ul class=\"sub-menu\"><a href=\"category/".$submenu->urlsubcategory."\">".$submenu->namesubcategory."</a><li>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                        ?>
```

The single menu works good on loops, but when the menu have submenu, the loops become false in structure.

```
ul
  li-a--Single Menu--/a-/li ->Have no SubMenu, Works Good
  li-a--Single Menu--/a-/li ->Have no SubMenu, Works Good
  li-a--Single Menu--/a-/li ->Have SubMenu, False Structure
    ul-class=submenu
       a-Sub Menu-/a
       li--/li
       ul-class=submenu
         a-Sub Menu-/a
         li--/li
    /ul
ul
```

The menu structure should become like this:

```
ul
  li-a--Single Menu--/a-/li
  li-a--Single Menu--/a-/li
  li-a-Single Menu With Sub Menu-/a-/li
    ul-class=submenu
      li-a-Sub Menu-/a-/li
      li-a-Sub Menu-/a-/li
      li-a-Sub Menu-/a-/li
    /ul
  li-a--Single Menu--/a-/li
  li-a--Single Menu--/a-/li
ul
```

Comment: Did you dump all your variables out to see what you have in your `$data["category"]`? Just make sure your `$menu->namesubcategory` may not be NULL

Comment: Hi @JofryHS, I've update and editing my script today. I use $data["category"] and $data["subcategory"] to throw the data. And Yes, $data["category"] is not NULL.

Comment: @Tomas's structure is different i think....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($category->result() as $menu){
echo "<li><a class=\"sf-with-ul\" href=\"category/".$menu->urlcategory."\">".$menu->namecategory."</a>";
$subcat = $subcategory->result();
if(count($subcat) > 0){

    echo "<ul class=\"sub-menu\">";
        foreach($subcat as $submenu){ 
        if ($menu->idcategory == $submenu->idcategory){
            echo "<li class=\"menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category\" style=\"white-space: normal; float: none; width: auto;\"><a class=\"sf-with-ul\" href=\"http://travellingbali.com/category/".$menu->urlcategory."/".$submenu->urlsubcategory."/\" style=\"float: none; width: auto;\">".$submenu->namesubcategory."</a>";                                   

            echo "</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";

}
echo "</li>";
}
```

try this. maybe work for you..

Answer (score 0):

your structure of printing ul li in sub menu is wrong it seems

Try this

```
   foreach($category->result() as $menu)
    {
       echo "<li><a class=\"sf-with-ul\" href=\"category/".$menu->urlcategory."\">".$menu->namecategory."</a>";
       /*check whether sub menu is there if so first print <ul> then <li><a>*/
       if(count($subcategory->result()) > 0 && is_array($subcategory->result()))
       {
             echo "<ul class=\"sub-menu\">";
             foreach($subcategory->result() as $key=>$submenu)
             {
               if ($menu->idcategory == $submenu->idcategory){
                echo "<li><a href=\"category/".$submenu->urlsubcategory."\">".$submenu->namesubcategory."</a></li>";
                }
             }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @plain-jane. I tried your looping, but they still print false.

Comment: I've tried your edited code, but they still print false structure. All sub-menu now print at the top of menu, then the main-menu print at the bottom of menu.So the sub-menu and main-menu have the same style, all became main-menu.

Comment: what is this true and false in the structure below?

Comment: Are you sure there are 3 sub menus in your second menu item?

Answer (score 0):

@plain-jane. I tried your looping, but they print:

```
<li><a>--</a></li> ->True
<li><a>--</a></li> ->True
  <ul class="submenu">--</ul> ->False
<li>--</li> ->False
  <ul class="submenu">--</ul> ->False
<li>--</li> ->False
```

On your loops, all sub-menu became first menu. They should become like this:

```
<li><a>-Menu-</a></li>
<li><a>-Menu-</a></li>
  <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a>-SubMenu-</a></li>
    <li><a>-SubMenu-</a></li>
    <li><a>-SubMenu-</a></li>
  </ul>
<li><a>-Menu-</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can do by this way: here this the function to create dropdown menu it's the same ways to create dynamic menu
[please check here](http://yuljet.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-create-menu-and-sub-menu-how-to.html)

I this it can help you.